# How to use the derivative (which has x and y in the answer) to approximate values of the function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation

For ethical reasons, I won't ask the exact assignment question:

For a function such as $4x^3 + 2y^3 -yx^2 = 49$. How could I use the derivative to estimate the values on the curve near a certain point? I am asked to create a table of values close to a point given to me. Since I have created the function above, I cannot give one as there is likely no pretty answer. So, if the solution requires this, how would I utilize it?

The derivative of this function is similar in nature to the one in my assignment, that being it has values of x *and* y. The derivative for this particular function is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2x(6x-y)}{x^2 -6y^2}
$$

I believe the solution lies in the using something similar to f(x) ≈ f(a) + f'(a)(x − a), but I do not know how to implement this. For my assignment in particular it asks me, after telling me to find values on the curve near x=1, y=2, to include the 0.96, 0.98, 1, 1.02, and 1.04 in my table of values. I can only assume this means the x values and find the subsequent y? I am not sure how to do this with the derivative considering if I put in a value of x, there are two unknowns: the value of y and the derivative itself.

Sorry I have waffled a bit, and I apologise if my wording makes things confusing. It is a manifestation of my own confusion.

Edit:
The next part of the question involves finding x values such that the tangent to the curve is horizontal, or vertical. How would I go about this? My initial response. for horizontal, is to make the derivative =0, but I have two variables? How could I find a vertical tangent?

Comment: I hope my edits and interpretations of your question are correct! Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you have learned about is the linear approximation
$$
f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)
$$
you should simply plug in $a=1,f(a)=2$ to this formula to have the linear approximation
$$
f(x)\approx 2-\tfrac8{23}(x-1)
$$
which should then be ready for you to estimate $f(x)$ for $x\in\{0.96,0.98,1.02,1.04\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel quite silly right now, but at least I know for the future! :)

Comment: @Skylineblue: No problem!

Comment: The next part of the question involves finding x values such that the tangent to the curve is horizontal, or vertical. How would I go about this? My initial response. for horizontal, is to make the derivative =0, but I have two variables? How could I find a vertical tangent?

Also, sorry for using a comment to ask this.

Comment: @Skylineblue: So you have an implicit relation between $x$ and $y$ and not $y$ as a function of $x$? Then you can find the derivative w.r.t. $y$ and put this equal to zero to find the vertical tangent.

Comment: The question's function is similar in nature to the one I have used as an example. So making F'(x) = (2x(6x−y))/(x^2−6y^2) = 0, the solutions are x = 0 and y=6x. for x = 0 that is a straight answer to check, but what about y=6x?

Comment: @Skylineblue: Substitute $6x$ for $y$ in the original equation and solve for $x$. In your example all terms becomes multiples of $x^3$ so that equation should give you a single solution.

Comment: @Skylineblue: Substitute $6x$ for $y$ in the original equation and solve for $x$. In your example all terms becomes multiples of $x^3$ so that equation should give you a single solution.

Comment: @Skylineblue: BTW vertical tangents will be singularities for $f'(x)$ so you could simply check the denominator $x^2-6y^2$ for zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think I need further working/proof beyond finding these values? Such as checking the nature of f'(x) on either side of these critical values? I've just tried to do such and it seems very very difficult to find the corresponding y values to plug into my f'(x) to do this test. I can do it with an online calculator though. But it also requires I put other x values in next to the x's I want, and finding the subsequent y's. Very clunky.

Also, what makes me believe I do not need to go to this level of proof is that they ask simply for the x values of these points.

Comment: Sorry. I've just realised what I was describing is for checking the nature of the turning points. Disregard that. But I still wonder if I need to have extra proof beyond deriving it from calculus?

Comment: @Skylineblue: If you have found a zero for the denominator which is not a zero for the numerator, then it is safe to say that $f'(x)$ tends to $\pm\infty$ there. The sign depends on the sign of the numerator but does not really matter here.

Comment: That makes sense. What do you think about further proof for the horizontal?